# Fazer um loop de elemento DOM javascript - Cada elemento numa <li>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo da memória e os ícones eles não estão indo um para cada li e sim a cada loop aparecendo mais um ícones nas li correspondentes.
Na última li aparece 16 ícones ao invés de um.

```js
const cards = [
    'fa fa-diamond',
    'fa fa-paper-plane-o',
    'fa fa-anchor',
    'fa fa-bolt',
    'fa fa-cube',    
    'fa fa-leaf',
    'fa fa-bicycle',
    'fa fa-bomb',
    'fa fa-diamond',
    'fa fa-paper-plane-o',
    'fa fa-anchor',
    'fa fa fa-bolt',
    'fa fa-cube',    
    'fa fa-leaf',
    'fa fa-bicycle',
    'fa fa-bomb'
];

let ul = document.getElementById('li');

let li = '';

for (i = 0; i<cards.length; i++) { 
    li += '<li class="card">' +
    '<i class=" ' +cards[i]+ '" </i>' +
    '</li>'  
    
    
};
document.getElementById('deck').innerHTML= li;



$("li").on('click' , function(){
    $(this).toggleClass(".card open show");             
        console.log("li");
        
});
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #ffffff url('../img/geometry2.png'); /* Background pattern from Subtle Patterns */
    font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*
 * Styles for the deck of cards
 */

.deck {
    width: 660px;
    min-height: 680px;
    background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
    padding: 32px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 0 3em;
}

.deck .card {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    background: #2e3d49;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
}

.deck .card.open {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    background: #02b3e4;
    cursor: default;
}

.deck .card.show {
    font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
    cursor: default;
    background: #02ccba;
    font-size: 33px;
}

/*
 * Styles for the Score Panel
 */

.score-panel {
    text-align: left;
    width: 345px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.score-panel .stars {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.score-panel .stars li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .restart {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game - Jogo da Memória</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
         <ul class="stars">
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
         </ul>

         <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

            <div class="restart">
          <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
         </div>
        </section>

        <ul id="deck" class="deck"> </ul>

        
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

texto em negrito

Comment: Faltou fechar o elemento `i` dentro do js.

Comment: Verdade  ! ! !  muito obrigado  ! ! ! ! !